# Normal Distribution (Solution explanation)

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

The average temperature of a particular tropical island is normally distributed with a mean of 74 degrees and a variance of 9 degrees

(a) If a random sample of 16 days has been taken, what is the probability that at least 12 of them will have temperatures higher than 70 degrees?

Method: (70-74)/3 : Gives us probability of 0.91 approximately. Found np = 14.56 and S.D = 1.144 
My doubt is in the final formula what will I replace 74 with?

Comment: It appears you want to use normal approximation to binomial in the final step, while you don't have to since the numbers are small and the probability you ask for is trivial to compute. But, if you're going to use it, you don't need 74 also because you seek for $P(X \geq 12)$, where $X$ is number of days having $> 70$ degrees.

Comment: Oh yes. My final answer is close to 0.9871. Is that correct?

Comment: That's sort of close, mainly because of a cancellation in errors made by not carrying sufficiently many significant digits, using an approximate calculation, and not employing a continuity correction.  However, $p\approx 0.91$ is close enough to $1$ and $n=16$ is sufficiently small that you need to be wary of using the Normal approximation to the Binomial distribution.  Use the Binomial distribution instead.